# How to create grouped textfield within Storyboards?

Tags: ios, cocoa, uistoryboard

Hey Guys i am trying to figure out how to build grouped textfields inside storyboards ? Any Ideas ?

Comment: What do you call "grouped textfields" ? Any screenshots of what you're looking for ?

Comment: Please be more specific in what you want to achieve

Comment: [link](http://images.tweaktown.com/news/2/3/23413_14_warning_facebook_mobile_for_ios_and_android_allows_easy_access_to_your_login_information.png)

Comment: This is what ive been looking for.

Comment: The easiest way that I've found is to add a tableView to your view and then use the usual tableViewDatasource methods to populate it.

Comment: you need to have them premade and in the attribute inspector of story boards you add it to "Background Image"

Comment: I tried it out, but then a got an error message that says to me that i just can use static table view cells inside a UITableViewController. so do i have to make my viewcontroller a tableviewcontroller ?

Comment: no, you can just use the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource protocols

Comment: If i implement the 2 protocols and connect my tableview datasource and delegate to the viewcontroller, i still got the same error message.

Comment: Yes , a static table view must be imbedded in a UITableViewController and will not work with a UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

Use a containerView in your main view and populate two rows as necessary.  You'll need to add a Cell template to the tableView to avoid the static cell error message.